# Are there any restaurants in Tokyo that serve Sannakji?

Tags: japan, food-and-drink, tokyo

I know that [Sannakji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sannakji) is originally Korean food, but I've seen on TV they've eaten that in Tokyo as well.

**Update:**
It was on a Finnish TV show called [Madventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madventures). You can find the clip on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sxCHcLiJVQ#t=9m55s

Comment: Do you happen to remember which show or channel that was on ?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it in [Shin-Okubo, Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Ckubo,_Tokyo) (Korean town).

Searching Yelp, [A lot of results](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=Shin-%C5%8Ckubo%2C+tokyo&ns=1#find_desc=sannakji) matching Sannakji and Shin-Okubo. Take a pick and try.

Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG1YrLAisRg) of a guy eating that in Shin-Okubo in Tokyo.